# Как конвертировать строку из парсера в число C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

Вопрос 1: Через парсер получаем строку "10д 5ч". (10 дней и 5 часов)
Надо ее конвертировать и получить время в часах (10*24+5) и получить число 245.
Пока что идея сделать через if и замену буквы на число, но это похоже на костыль, а не решение.

Вопрос 2: Число (int) надо конвертировать в дни и часы и вывести через TextView

Что подскажете?

Comment: Задать два вопроса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

За время в C# отвечает [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan) и с ним вам стоит работать.

**Считываем значение:**

У таких объектов, как `TimeSpan` и `DateTime` (а также их аналоги) есть два метода (`Parse` и `ParseExact`), которые как раз и отвечают за "чтение" времени из `String`. `Parse` будет полезен тогда, когда время идет в стандартном формате (по типу hh:mm:ss). `ParseExact` в этом плане более гибкий и позволяет настраивать формат "парса" времени.

Воспользуемся `ParseExact`:

```
var time = TimeSpan.ParseExact("10д 5ч", "d'д 'h'ч'", null);
```

Здесь мы разбили входные данные, отделив обычный текст от значений самого времени. Сами же значения заменяем на нужный нам [формат](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Также метод требует культуру, тут уже сами думайте, нужна она вам или нет...

**Получаем необходимые данные:**

> получить время в часах (10*24+5) и получить число 245

При использование нужного типа данных мы с легкостью можем оперировать этими данными так, как заходим. В данном случае все, что вам нужно, это узнать значение свойства `TotalHours`:

```
var totalHours = time.TotalHours;
```

**Обратная конвертация:**

> Число (int) надо конвертировать в дни и часы

Для этого есть такие методы как `FromHours()`. Принимают они `double` значение и отдают `TimeSpan`:

```
var result = TimeSpan.FromHours(totalHours);
```

Ну а как выводить, это уже смотрите сами. Обычно используется `.ToString();` который может также принимать [настраиваемый формат](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), так что просто поиграйтесь с этим и думаю поймете.

В общем удачи в изучении C#!

Comment: даже не знал о существовании TryParse. Спасибо за подсказку. Да с выводом уже разберусь самостоятельно)

Comment: появилась еще одна проблема. Иногда строка может содержать не "10д 5ч" а "2.3м" (2.3 месяца). 
Я так понимаю надо делать проверку через if и в разых методах подсчитывать часы?

Comment: @BogdanIlkiv TimeSpan - это время (часы, минуты, секунды), в него месяц не запихнуть... Для работы с датами нужно использовать DateTime. Так, что да, придется делать как то через if и разбирать и приводить к разным типам данных. Как условие if можете использовать TryParseExact - он возвращает bool, а через out можно возвращать результат (прим: `if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, "d'д 'h'ч'", null, out var time)){var totalHours = time.TotalHours; //...}`.